# jQuery: Adding HTML inside a dynamic list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a piece of jquery that dynamically creates an unordered list:

```
var get_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/notes/get/"+<?php echo $id;?>;

$.get(get_url, function(data) {

$.each(data,function(index, arr)
   {
      var opt = $('<li />'); 

      opt.text(arr['body']);
      $('#notes-list').append(opt);
   });
});
```

This produces the correct list but I want to add < pre> tags around the text in the list item.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I've tried opt.innerHTML = "< pre />"; but no luck.

Thanks,

Billy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **could** just append the HTML instead of an object.

```
var get_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/notes/get/"+<?php echo $id;?>;

$.get(get_url, function(data) {
    $.each(data,function(index, arr){
       var html = '<li><pre>' + arr['body'] + '</pre></li>';
       $('#notes-list').append(html);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (which involves appending a `$('<pre>')` element to ur `obt` element):

```
var get_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/notes/get/"+<?php echo $id;?>;

$.get(get_url, function(data) {
$.each(data,function(index, arr)
   {
      var opt = $('<li>'); 
      var text = $('<pre>', {text: arr['body']})
      opt.append(text);
      $('#notes-list').append(opt);
   });
});
```